# Possible to create a function that returns PickerView with data?

Tags: swift3, uipickerview, custom-function, swift-framework

I'm trying to create a framework that does an API call and creates a PickerView with the populated data from the API call. The iOS client will import this framework and call that one exposed function that should return the PickerView with the loaded data in it.

I managed to create a function that creates the PickerView but can't figure out how to insert the data inside the PickerView.

```
    // Framework Side

    public static func returnPickerView() -> UIPickerView {
    let apple = ["apple", "orange", "durian", "banana"]

    let customPicker = UIPickerView()

    customPicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
    customPicker.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    customPicker.layer.borderWidth = 1

    return customPicker
}
```

Comment: you should inherit `UIPickerView` and create you custom class

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem was to create a custom class like what JuicyFruit said.

```
class CustomPickerView: UIPickerView {  
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        dataSource = self
        delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

extension CustomPickerView: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        ...
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        ...
    }
}

extension CustomPickerView: UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        ...
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        ...
    }
}
```